# AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Neo4j

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, neo4j, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to web application development.I developed a web application(rest web service) that has both mysql and neo4j database. now I want to host it on the internet for a mobile app to consume.I was wandering if anyone could point me to steps i need to take to successfully deploy it on AWS.I have looked in to EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk and confused of how i should proceed further.
Thank you

Comment: I owuld think AWS would work pretty well. I used Google CE, spun up a new linux vm, installed jdk 7, unzipped community 2.2.0-M03, started neo4j, opened up 7473 to the big Internet and was rolling.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you check out [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com/). They're the only game in town as far as hosted Neo4j goes, as far as I know. They do a great job.

Comment: [Disclaimer: I'm one of the founders of [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com)] There is a [Cloud Formation Template](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-puppet/blob/master/README.CLOUDFORMATION.md) maintained by Neo Technology, that you can use to provision your own Neo4j instance on EC2. That said, I'd urge you to try out [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com). We offer fully-managed hosted Neo4j instances on different AWS regions and at different requirement levels (from dev to production). Feel free to ping me at alberto at graphenedb dot com if you have any questions!